# this.gridApi.refreshInfiniteCache() is not clearing selectedRows

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-react

I am using Infinite Row Model and when i deleted the selected row from Grid then i am calling refreshing cache so lets say i deleted the selected **id = 1** 
but after **refreshInfiniteCache()**; new row comes from DB via **getRows()** its **id = 2** and that selected row does not get un-select auto and if i am clicking on delete button again then I am getting two rows in selectedData. Why is that? from **this.gridApi.getSelectedRows()** and **getSelectedNodes()** i am getting two rows previous row id = 1 and next row which came after delete that is id = 2. I should get only one row id = 2 not id = 1 again i have deleted this row and refreshed cache. Please tell me am i  missing something?

```
deleteRow() {
const selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
this.assetTypeService.deleteAssetType(selectedData[0].AssetTypeID)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    this.gridApi.refreshInfiniteCache();
  })
}
```

Comment: provide the code for `deleteRow` function

Comment: @un.spike It is already in my question.

Answer (score 1):

> [**`refreshInfiniteCache()`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/#api-infinite-scrolling) : Marks all the currently loaded blocks in the cache for reload. If you have 10 blocks in the cache, all 10 will be marked for reloading. **The old data will continue to be displayed until the new data is loaded.**

So you can call `refreshInfiniteCache()` if you will replace all grid data via `setRowData(rows)`

> [**`setRowData(rows)`**](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#data)   Set new rows into the grid.

or you need to [update the grid data](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#removing-rows) after completing a delete request.

```
params.api.updateRowData({remove:[...array of data-objects to remove...]});
```

Comment: as I already told i am using infinite row model so i think i can not use updateRowData or setRowData in this. Can i ?

Comment: and what is a diff for `CRUD` operations? just try

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code inside the deleteRow() function:

```
   gridApi.getSelectedNodes().forEach(node => {
      var id = node.data.id;
      var rowNode = gridApi.getRowNode(id);
      rowNode.setSelected(false);
    })
```